# Show registry information with my docker image

Tags: docker

On my laptop I can pull an image using

```
docker pull maven:3-alpine
```

On a different machine, the default registry is different, so this image is not found.

Is it possible to see where images come from? So I can include that when I pull the image?

For example

```
docker pull myregistry.com/somefolder/maven:3-alpine
```

Comment: Default registry is supposed to be docker.io ... What's the message on the second machine when you try to pull the same image ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just mean get the registry from image, the answer is no, the image itself not have the information for registry.

But if you not ever change registry after the image has pulled, then you can use next to check the registry:

```
$ docker info | grep Registry
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

Then, on another machine, you could use for example `docker pull index.docker.io/ubuntu:14.04` to pull it.

If above `grep` not get the default registry, but something like `http://myregistry.com`, then on another machine you could use `docker pull myregistry.com/ubuntu:14.04`.